# Why jump into the unavailable address(GDB)

Tags: gdb, disassembly

When I debugged a code, and found:

```
0x08048500 <+0>:  push %ebp
0x08048501 <+1>:  mov %esp,%ebp
...
0x08048563 <+99>: jmp 0x8048567 <Postion+103>   <===0x8048567 doesn't exist an instruction.
0x08048565 <+101>: dec %edx
0x08048566 <+102>: cmp %bh,%al
0x08048568 <+104>: test %edx,%esp
```

Q: Why does "jmp 0x8048567" jump into <+103>? It doesn't exist an instruction. What's the point? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does "jmp 0x8048567" jump into <+103>? It doesn't exist an instruction

It's very likely that the instruction at `0x8048567` does exist. You can see it with `x/4i 0x8048567`.

What is probably happening is that instruction at `0x8048565` doesn't really exist, but GDB doesn't know that, continues disassembling one instruction after another, and gets out of sync with the real instruction stream.

Comment: How can I get the real instruction at 0x8048565?

Comment: There *is no* real instruction at `0x8048565`, there are only bytes that you can interpret as decimal, or hex, or floating point, or as instruction. If you interpret bytes at `0x8048565` as instructions, you would get `dec %edx` that GDB already showed you.